# onclick and href doesn't work together on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I use the the kendo ui splitview with two panes. This is what I tried:

```
<ul>
<li data-icon="net"><a id="clicker" onclick="testfunc()" href="#emptytestpage" data-target="main-pane">Empty </a></li>
</ul>
```

```
function testfunc(){


    alert("TEST");
}
</script>
```

This works great on google chrome with win7 or other desktop computers, but when i
start it on a tablet with android or on a iphone it doesn't work. On mobile devices the onlick event doesn't work and i don't know why. How can i open a new page with href and start a function at the same time and why does it work on desktop and not with mobile devices?

Can someone help me please?

Comment: try with `ontouchend="testfunc()"` instead of `onclick="testfunc()"`

Comment: That work's but when I use ontouchend event it doesn't work on desktop version anymore. How can I use one event for touch and desktop version or should I use two different html documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove both inline `onclick` and `ontouchend` events. Then you may dynamically add event for `click` or `touchend` based on platform: mobile or desktop. I've made also a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XspQ4/2/).

Something along these lines:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clickHandler = function(e) {
            // Do other stuff on desktop;
            alert('desktop');
        },
        touchendHandler = function(e) {
            // Do other stuff on mobile;
            alert('mobile');
        },
        initClickOrTouchEventFor = function(elementSelector) {
            var el = $(elementSelector);

            // We're on mobile.
            if (mobilecheck()) {
                console.log('attaching touchend event on mobile');

                el.on('touchend', touchendHandler);
            }
            // We're on desktop.
            else {
                console.log('attaching click event on desktop');

                el.on('click', clickHandler);
            }
        };

    initClickOrTouchEventFor('#clicker');
});
```

Comment: There will always be "desktop" appears regardless of whether I use the tablet or pc

Comment: Most probably you haven't included the `mobilecheck` function. You can find it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XspQ4/2/). `window.mobilecheck = function() ...`

Comment: I included that mobilecheck from the fiddle demo.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't put anything on the elements attributes, but set an event listener in jquery.

```
$("#clicker").on("click",function(evt){

    evt.stopPropagation();evt.preventDefault(); //Prevents the href

    //Do your thing

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uA8b6/ (Tested on an iPad Mini)

Comment: but I want that the "href" is also executed.

Comment: @mpears Add the effect of the href into the event listener is probably the easiest.   So if you want to use an anchor: `$(window).scrolltop( $("#element").offset().top )`  or if you just want it to be a link: `location.href="http://google.com";`   Hope that helps.